# python selenium not load firefox extension

Tags: python, selenium

I try to load firefox extension with python-selenium, but not working, this is my current code >

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", False)
profile.add_extension('canvasblocker2.xpi')
#profile.add_extension("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/bot/canvasblocker2.xpi")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

I tested with both version, complete path/ is same directory .. and not working, firefox start with clean browser.

where is the error ? I have python 3.7.4 / selenium '3.141.0'